# Accessing "Planned Velocity" field available in iteration using Rally API 2.0

Tags: iteration, rally

I am trying to access the "Planned Velocity" field which is available for Iterations using the Rally 2.0 API and a WsapiDataStore object.  Even when using fetch: true in development to pull back all fields, I do not see this field.

Does anyone know how to access this field?

Thanks,
Michael

Code excerpt:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        this.loadIterations(); 
    },

    loadIterations: function() {                
        var iterations = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'Iteration',
            autoLoad: true,
            fetch: ['ObjectID', 'Name', 'EndDate', 'PlannedVelocity'],
            sorters: [
                {property: 'EndDate', direction: 'ASC'}
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, data, success) {
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
                        console.info('ID: ', record.get('ObjectID'), 
                            '  Name: ', record.get('Name'),                             
                            '  EndDate: ', record.get('EndDate'), 
                            '  PlannedVelocity: ', record.get('PlannedVelocity'));
                    });
                }, scope: this
            }
        });        
}    
});
```

Console Output:

> ```
> ID: 12351801409 Name: AGR 4.2 Iteration 1 EndDate: Date {Tue Jul 02 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)} PlannedVelocity: undefined
> ID: 12351802932 Name: AGR 4.2 Iteration 2 EndDate: Date {Tue Jul 23 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)} PlannedVelocity: undefined
> ID: 13298563033 Name: AGR 4.2 Iteration 3 EndDate: Date {Tue Aug 13 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)} PlannedVelocity: undefined
> ID: 12351804786 Name: AGR 4.2 Iteration 4 EndDate: Date {Tue Sep 03 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)} PlannedVelocity: undefined
> ```

Rally Info:

> ```
> Name  End Date    Planned Velocity
> AGR 4.2 Iteration 1   7/2/2013    29.0 Points
> AGR 4.2 Iteration 2   7/23/2013   82.0 Points
> AGR 4.2 Iteration 3   8/13/2013   70.5 Points
> AGR 4.2 Iteration 4   9/3/2013    72.4 Points
> ```

Answer (score 0):

PlannedVelocity is the name of the field to include in the fetch (no spaces).  If that still doesn't work please provide some example code so it is easier to see what might be going on.

Comment: Added code, console output, and data copied from Rally.  Planned velocity field does not show up.

Comment: I tested your code. The code correctly returns PlannedVelocity for me. The only change I made is that there is a typo in your post: `'  Name: ', ecord.get('Name')` I am sure it is correct in your code, otherwise you would get "ecord is not defined" error.

Comment: Thank you.  I will talk with our Rally support.  We have one other odd thing going on in our workspace that works for other people.  At least I can confirm that I have been trying the correct way.  Typo so to me reformatting code that looked really bad when I pasted to Stack Overflow...